# How can I see the full output of my Python code in VS Code terminal?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have a Python script that produces a large amount of output in my VS Code terminal. However, some of the lines are shortened and displayed as "..." so I cannot see the complete output. I want to view the entire output of my script in the terminal.

I have tried looking for solutions in other similar questions but haven't found a solution yet. Here is an example of my code and the truncated output:

```
import random
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

class DescriptiveStatistics:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
    
    def frequency_table(self):
        possible_values = sorted(set(self.data))
        counters = {x: 0 for x in possible_values}
        for x in counters:
            counters[x] = self.data.count(x)
        cumulative_relative_frequency = 0.0
        table_lines = []
        for k, v in counters.items():
            cumulative_relative_frequency += v/len(self.data)
            table_lines.append([k, v, v/len(self.data) ,cumulative_relative_frequency])
        return pd.DataFrame(
            table_lines,
            columns=[
                "Values",
                "Absolute Frequency",
                "Relative Frequemcy",
                "Cumulative Relative Frequency"
            ])

def main():
    print(f"===== Frequency Table =====")
    data = [random.randint(1,999) for _ in range(100)]
    descriptive_statistics = DescriptiveStatistics(data)
    print(descriptive_statistics.frequency_table())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Output:

```
===== Frequency Table =====
    Values  Absolute Frequency  Relative Frequemcy  Cumulative Relative Frequency
0        2                   1                0.01                           0.01
1       16                   1                0.01                           0.02
2       30                   1                0.01                           0.03
3       35                   1                0.01                           0.04
4       42                   1                0.01                           0.05
..     ...                 ...                 ...                            ...
93     954                   1                0.01                           0.96
94     955                   1                0.01                           0.97
95     959                   1                0.01                           0.98
96     983                   1                0.01                           0.99
97     995                   1                0.01                           1.00
```

Comment: `print(descriptive_statistics.frequency_table().to_string())`?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the settings of the terminal:

Open the VS Code settings by pressing Ctrl + , (Windows/Linux) or Command + , (macOS). In the search bar, type "terminal.integrated.scrollback".

Increase the value of "terminal.integrated.scrollback" to a larger number, like 9000 or something. This setting determines how many lines of output the terminal can store in its buffer.
Save the settings and restart VS Code.

Comment: This seems like more of a question about `pandas` truncating a dataframe `print` then a VS Code setting.

Answer (score 0):

Settings => (Search for "scrollback") => Then you can increase the number of lines for "Terminal › Integrated: Scrollback".

Comment: You'll have the same output regardless of any settings since its `pandas` truncating the output. Not VS Code.

Comment: tried but doesn't work